# Winter Bash 2014

Tags: discussion, winter-bash

Just wanted to see if anyone was against us joining the Winter Bash for 2014. We usually do it each year, we have to fill out a form this year to participate. I can fill out the form, just need to know if anyone is wildly opposed to the idea. Usually, joining it adds something to our PotW header, and we have to make sure we don't wipe that out when updating it.

Comment: Hmm.. I signed us up last night... We always have.

Comment: Sorry, probably jumped the gun on it, but since people can opt out individually I can't see it being an issue.

Answer (score 4):

I am in favor. Let's bash away!